# NetBeans: Cannot Start Tomcat ("The system cannot find the file specified")

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I just installed NetBeans 8.2 along with Tomcat 8.0.27 on a Windows server VDI instance.  I am an experienced NetBeans/Tomcat user (mostly on Mac OS recently) so this is nothing new for me.

After the NetBeans and Tomcat installation I try to start Tomcat from NetBeans' `Services` window like I always have.  Unfortunately Tomcat fails to start, and this is the only output in the NetBeans `Output` window in the `Apache Tomcat 8.0.27` tab:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\dev\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "D:\dev\jdk18"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\dev\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\bootstrap.jar;D: \dev\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've verified that all the locations in the above message actually do exist so I don't know what file it is that cannot be found.  If it was some sort of permission issue I would expect it to say as much (right?).

You can see here that I have some non-standard NetBeans and Tomcat installation locations, but I have also tried with the standard installation locations and I have the same result (these locations avoid the company's intrusive virus scanner).

I can start Tomcat from the command line using `startup.bat` or `catalina.bat` so I know the Tomcat installation is OK.  However, this isn't nearly as convenient as doing it from NetBeans.

What can I do to figure out why NetBeans can't start Tomcat?  I've looked in a few log files but there's nothing about Tomcat.  Maybe I'm not seeing all the NetBeans log files.

I don't know where else to look or what else to try.  I've used NetBeans and Tomcat for years and have never had this problem.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've been having this issue in the past few days and that was driving me crazy. I just figured it out how to solve this (and is pretty simple). Go to Tools -> Options -> General -> Proxy Settings: No Proxy.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that worked, thank you!!  Any idea **why** it worked?  I've never had this problem before although I'm guessing it has something to do with the VDI setup (our corporate dev platform so I don't have a say in it).

Comment: Don't know too. It never happened before so I couldn't say why. At least it solves our problem, I'll let explanation for some more experienced guys =P

Comment: This is because the standard Windows settings are too loose. My installation of Netbeans 10 fails as described with the System settings, but works like music with a manual configuration with the following exceptions: `10*, 172*, <local>*, localhost, 127.0.0.1`. You need to choose `manual proxy settings` in the `General` options tab, then click `More` to specify the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to open netbeans>Tools>Options>General>Proxy Settings: No proxy.
Restart NetBeans and it works.